# Can't get a value printed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am just practicing by trying different things in the Chrome console. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong with the following code, but I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

...for this code:

```
function printToConsole(val1, val2) {
console.log("The value of" +  val1 + "and" val2 + " is " + (val1 + val2 ));}
```

Comment: You're missing a plus after "and".

Comment: Completely off-topic: It would be more correct to say "The sum", not the "The value" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `+` sign, Therefore javascript doesn't know you need to concatenate the further string and throws error not closing the function call (missing ')').

```js
function printToConsole(val1, val2) {
  console.log("The value of " + val1 + " and " +
    val2 + " is " + (val1 + val2)); //missing + after 'and' 
}

printToConsole(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function printToConsole(val1, val2) {
  console.log("The value of " +  val1 + " and " + val2 + " is " + (val1 + val2));
}
```

You are missing the concat operation (+) after the "and" string.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above you are missing the **+** sign in string between "and" and val2.

To add further there are lot of syntax checking tools available. ESLint (http://eslint.org/) is one of them. It works with most of the text editors and will highlight these kind of syntax errors immediately.

Below is one more flavor to write above code

(function(val1, val2) {console.log("The value of " +  val1 + "and " + val2 + " is " + (val1 + val2 ));})(1,2);